# VBA - Only Check for Date inside a DD/MM/YYYY - HH/MM/SS value

Tags: vba, excel, date

I've checked through multiple topics but I unfortunately couldn't find the solution I need.

I have cells which needs to include Date and Time in the following custom format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

And I have something that check those cells to see if it matches. If it does, it notifies me that it is approaching its due time.

```
Dim MyLimit         As Double

MyLimit = Date

Set FormulaRange = Range("E5:E35")    
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If .Value = MyLimit Then
                *Do the action*
```

This works properly if I set a date value such as 02/05/2016 in the cells, as it default to midnight and it triggers the action. Although 02/05/2016 2:45 PM doesn't work.

So what I need it to do is to check only the first part of the cell for the date value and trigger the action if it fits with today's date.

I tried a few solutions such as:

```
Dim MyLimit         As Double

MyLimit = CDate(format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy"))

Set FormulaRange = Range("E5:E35")    
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If .Value = MyLimit Then
                *Do the action*
```

and

```
Dim MyLimit         As Date

MyLimit = Format((Now), "DD/MM/YYYY")

Set FormulaRange = Range("E5:E35")    
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If .Value = MyLimit Then
                *Do the action*
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't detect that it should do the action as the date = today.

Anyone can enlighten me on this?

Actual script:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function AutoRun()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "TaskTracker2"
End Function

Public Sub TaskTracker2()
Dim FormulaCell          As Range
Dim FormulaRange    As Range
Dim NotSentMsg      As String
Dim MyMsg           As String
Dim SentMsg         As String
Dim SendTo          As String
Dim CCTo            As String
Dim BCCTo           As String
Dim MyLimit         As Double
Dim MyLimit2        As Double


NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"
SendTo = Range("D2")
CCTo = Range("E2")
BCCTo = Range("F2")

MyLimit = Date
MyLimit2 = ((Round(Now * 1440, 0) - 30) / 1440)

Set FormulaRange = Range("E5:E35")
On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If DateValue(.Value) = MyLimit Then
                MyMsg = SentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    strTO = SendTo
                    strCC = CCTo
                    strBCC = BCCTo
                    strSub = "[Task Manager] Reminder that you need to: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value
                    strBody = "Hello Sir, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "This email is to notify that you that your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value & " with the following note: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & " is nearing its Due Date." & vbNewLine & "It would be wise to complete this task before it expires!" & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Truly yours," & vbNewLine & "Task Manager"
                    If sendMail(strTO, strSub, strBody, strCC) = True Then MyMsg = SentMsg

                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If

            If .Value = MyLimit2 Then
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

Next FormulaCell
AutoRun


ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what I need it to do is to check only the first part of the cell for the date value

Use the `DateValue` function, e.g.:

```
 If DateValue(.Value) = MyLimit Then
     ' *Do the action*
```

NB: a `Date` type consists of Date **and** Time parts.

The `DateValue` function returns only the *Date Part* of a `Date` type. There is also the `TimeValue` function which returns only the `Time Part` from a `Date` type.

Some revisions for your Mismatch error, tested with the value `2/5/2016 14:45`:

```
Dim MyLimit As Date

MyLimit = Date

Set FormulaRange = Range("E5:E35")
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If DateValue(.Value) = MyLimit Then
                ' Do something...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It does trigger the option although I get an error message each time. Ming that I do receive the notification.

Comment: I get a 13 Type Mismatch error. I'll put the whole script in the original message so you can look it up :)

Comment: `MyLimit` is of type Double. Why?  Dates are restricted to `Long` data type. (I haven't debugged this yet, just making an educated guess). You may also try `DateValue(CDate(.Value))`

Comment: See revision, cast `MyLimit As Date` and I think that will take care of it.

Comment: I had tried to Dim MyLimit   As Date but it didn't work. The DateValue(CDate(.Value)) does work though :)

Thanks a lot David!